# how to use delicate function without including any event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some functions which don't need any event for calling, like these

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var t = new $.TextboxList('#form_tags_input', {  });
});
```

and this

```
$(function() {
    $('.tags').tagsInput({width:'auto'});
});
```

The problem is that I have to call them in a dynamically created post with jQuery. If there is any even then yes, I can use the delicate function for this purpose. But here no event is included.

How should I make this function to work for a component which is created dynamically by jQuery?

I am new in JavaScript and jquery so please edit my code to provide me an answer.

Comment: `$('body').on('DOMNodeInserted', ".tags", function(){ $(this).tagsInput({width:'auto'}); });`

Comment: Perhaps you mean "delegated", not "delicate".  Delegation in the browser is ONLY for events that propagate.  It is not applicable for what you are wanting to do.  You will have to either monitor the DOM for newly added elements or you will have to just call your methods on newly added elements.

Comment: hi learner, its not working

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/XaTCh/754/ check this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this function it will see for the node first and then will open the menu attached with that element.

```
$('body').on('DOMNodeInserted', ".tags", function(){ 
  $(this).tagsInput({width:'auto'}); 
});
```

Hope it helps.
Cheers!